# Jquery .html() does nothing with element with random html ID created with laravel (php)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

So my problem is that i have multiple elements on the page with a random id.
But jquery does nothing when the code is running (but finds the element), But does when the id is hardcoded;

Generate id:

```
@php
    $id = \Illuminate\Support\Str::random(5);
@endphp
```

Blade (with hardcoded "a" to prevent numbers from being in the first slot):

```
<div id="a{{$id}}" class="@if(isset($class)) {{$class}} @endif">
    <div class="text-center p-5">
        <div class="spinner-border" role="status"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script tag (below the Blade html code):

```
window.onload = function () {
        let url = '{{$url}}';
        $.ajax({
            'url': url,
            'method': 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (html) {
                $(`#a{{$id}}`).empty()
                $(`#a{{$id}}`).html(html)
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('e')
            }
        })
    };
```

What i tried:

1. Different "quote" types " ' `
2. Hardcoded id (That works :S )

Frontend HTML code on render:

```
<div id="aGwGES" class="">
    <div class="text-center p-5">
        <div class="spinner-border" role="status"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        let url = '/blablabla';
        $.ajax({
            'url': url,
            'method': 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (html) {
                $(`#aGwGES`).empty()
                $(`#aGwGES`).html(html)
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('e')
            }
        })
    };
</script>
```

Result:
Nothing happens (exept for the ajax call)
Loader stays there

Extra images:

Frontend html: https://i.ibb.co/fFGrmGN/image.png

Console: https://i.ibb.co/QpY11Vm/image.png

Element that should be empty (no loader):
https://i.ibb.co/8DYVDVt/image.png

Comment: Remember that PHP renders before the page is sent to the browser, and javascript/jquery works after the page has been sent. Look at the source code in your browser to see if the values have been output by PHP.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Yes, They do, Look at the "Frontend HTML code on render" section in my post. When i hardcode the id both in the html an js to "aTest". the code works

Comment: @u_mulder No errors.

Comment: With `'` or `"` quotes everything should work.

Comment: are you using `id="a{{$id}}"`on multiple elements ?

Comment: I have added images to better show my issue

Comment: @N69S Yes, I checked all of them, And they all have a unique id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was this line:

```
window.onload = function () {
```

I am not 100% sure if I am correct, But the problem was that I overwrite the onload function.
And that made only 1 work, The last one.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/fvcmrn4z/

it skips all other scripts and goes to the last one,

Answer (score 0):

it might just be that success is never reached cause of `'method'` & `'url'` format. try this

```js
window.onload = function () {
        let url = '{{$url}}';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).done( function (html) {
            $(`#a{{$id}}`).empty()
            $(`#a{{$id}}`).html(html)
        }).fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('e')
        });
    };
```

You did maybe try the first code with `.get()` then switched to `.ajax()`

Comment: Nope. This has the same result, It reaches .done, i added a extra log message, nothing happens. My code reaches success method. I added extra console logs in my code that you can see in the "frontend html" image and the "console" image in my post